# JQuery UI Rotatable, problems with radians option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image]

```js
let idArrow = 1; //the value here is a number ID from DB

let pos_rot = -2.42403827195133; //if I pass a value directly here 
//it works fine like in the live code
//while if I pass the value retrieved from DB through AJAX request in the response
//it behave as I described in the description of the problem

let newArrow = `<div id="` + idArrow + `" class="arrow arrow_` + idArrow + `" style="position:absolute;
       top: 100px;
       left: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       cursor: pointer;"></div>`;



var params = {
  //starting rotation angle
  radians: pos_rot //THIS OPTION GIVES ME PROBLEMS STARTING FROM SECOND ROTATION
                  //SO IT FREEZES ON ANGLE 0

} //close params

$(newArrow).draggable().rotatable(params).appendTo('#body');
```

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff3c00;
  z-index: 95;
}

.arrow::after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  left: -2.5px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 96;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 4px 12px 4px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #ff3c00 transparent;
}

.ui-rotatable-handle {
  position: relative;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(jQuery-UI-Rotatable-Elements/rotate.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  left: -3px;
  bottom: -3px;
  z-index: 97;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable@1.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>

<body id="body">
</body>
```

I have an issue about the radians option passed within the params of rotatable function (link to the official documentation https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable).

The problem is that if I type directly a number for the angle after the radians option, in the browser it keeps the rotatable functionality of the object with the starting angle of the value typed, but if I pass a global variable (in this case pos_rot) in the browser I can see the starting rotation, it works fine with on the first rotation, but on the second rotation it snaps directly to angle 0.

The problem exists also if I have just the radians option, without the stop option inside params.

Why this behaviour and how can i solve this problem?

```js
let idArrow; //the value here is a number ID from DB
let pos_rot; //the value here is a rotation in radians passed from DB

var params = {
  // Callback fired on rotation end
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    //setTimeout
    clearTimeout(rotateTimer);
    rotateTimer = setTimeout(function() {

      //function to get rotation angle
      $.fn.rotationInfo = function() {
        var el = $(this),
          tr = el.css("-webkit-transform") || el.css("-moz-transform") || el.css("-ms-transform") || el.css("-o-transform") || '',
          info = {
            rad: 0,
            deg: 0
          };
        if (tr = tr.match('matrix\\((.*)\\)')) {
          tr = tr[1].split(',');
          if (typeof tr[0] != 'undefined' && typeof tr[1] != 'undefined') {
            info.rad = Math.atan2(tr[1], tr[0]);
            info.deg = parseFloat((info.rad * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1));
          }
        }
        return info;
      };
      let rotation = $('.arrow_' + idArrow).rotationInfo().rad;

      //AJAX request to update values
      $.ajax({
        url: 'procedure/update_rotation.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          id: idArrow,
          rot: rotation
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("New rotation: " + rotation); //here the value gets updated correctly
        }
      });
    }, 150); //close setTimeout

  }, //close stop function

  //starting rotation
  radians: pos_rot //THIS OPTION GIVES ME PROBLEMS STARTING FROM SECOND ROTATION, SO IT FREEZES ON ANGLE 0

} //close params
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP and CSS, without any such code? Can you share more details, such that others can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I updated the code for a live version. PHP is because the AJAX request that let me retrieve pos_rot from DB, points at an external .php file. However i already applied trim on the response i get, and the value in radians to variable pos_rot gets assigned correctly, so I don't know why the strange behaviour..

Comment: So, is this a PHP problem after all? Is the payload that is sent to the server constructed as expected? If yes, this looks completely unrelated to PHP to me. If not, share more details

Comment: Yeah, I also don't think it's related to php. After I tried different methods to pass the value of starting angle to radians option, I think it's related to radians option itself, but I cannot understand why. Because the starting position of the angle is rendered correctly, it is passed correctly, but don't understand why freezes after the first rotation

Comment: I tried to transform all values in degrees, and I found out that the degrees option instead of radians works like it should be, so I resolved the problem in another way. I was using radians because it was default from rotatable plugin, but in the end it really was the radians option the problem for the behaviour. Thanks for your feedbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that is indeed a problem with "radians" option, because with "degrees" it gives no problems and works as it should do. If you incur in this problem, just use degrees option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).